# Wekan Jade mockup template

Tags: pug

I am new to Wekan. I noticed it uses Jade. I am novice but familiar with Jade. Where is the `{{ _add-list}}` value stored or initialized.  See the following:

```
template(name="addListForm")
  .list.js-list.list-composer.js-list-composer
    .list-header
      +inlinedForm(autoclose=false)
        input.list-name-input.full-line(type="text" placeholder="{{_ 'add-list'}}"
          autocomplete="off" autofocus)
        .edit-controls.clearfix
          button.primary.confirm(type="submit") {{_ 'save'}}
          a.fa.fa-times-thin.js-close-inlined-form
      else
        a.open-list-composer.js-open-inlined-form
          i.fa.fa-plus
          | **{{_ 'add-list'}}**
```

Also is **`template(name="addListForm")`** a call to `addListForm.jade` template. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the {{ _add-list}}? This value is stored in the local directory in Wekan root folder.